# wxPython PopupWindow, list out of range when in range

Tags: python, list, class, wxpython

I have this class here to open up a quick wx.PopupWindow class that is called from a wx.Frame wxButton

The class:

```
class popupInfo(wx.PopupWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        wx.PopupWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel = panel
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("GREY")

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[0],pos =(10,20))
        st2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[1],pos =(10,40))
        st3 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[2],pos =(10,60))
        st4 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[3],pos =(10,80))
        st5 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[4],pos =(10,100))
        st6 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[5],pos =(10,120))
        st7 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[6],pos =(10,140))
        st8 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, finalSemester[7],pos =(10,160))

        self.SetSize((400, 400))
        panel.SetSize((400, 400))

        self.Centre()
```

The code returns that all my indexed lists are out of range when they are declared outside of any class. Why is this?

Comment: Without seeing how finalSemester is declared and/or manipulated during the run of your program I can't tell you a great deal except that by the time this code runs, whatever it's finding there is not a minimum of 8 entries long.

Comment: It's declared merely as a list, outside of both wx Classes, and in the wx.Frame class it runs through assigns it no less than 8 indexes.

Comment: Use / missing use of the `global` keyword, possibly in the function that is supposed to assign entries into the list?  Try `print(finalSemester)` right before your StaticText creation?

Comment: Yeah, apparently when I run it through the operation it only saved it to finalSemester1 inside of the operation. Would I define it as global to globally save things to it?

Comment: Use of global variables should be avoided where possible, simply because they're more difficult to debug and produce unexpected behaviors (as your example demonstrates).  I'd suggest either making it an instance variable of whatever the parent class to this class is, or passing it into this class as an argument.

Comment: Worked, thanks! If you put your answer into the answer section I will approve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your finalSemester array is outside the scope of your function, python expects you are creating a local one, and you can't add elements that way.

you could use global, but you'd be better off just passing your array
as an argument into the initializer.